# How to create recurring profile in paypal for specific period

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I wanted the payment to be like 1$ for first month and 5$/month for 5 years or specific period .
So, I tried "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile"

```
$fields['method']='CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile';
$fields['USER'] = Configuration::get('PAYPAL_API_USER');
$fields['PWD'] = Configuration::get('PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD');
$fields['SIGNATURE'] = Configuration::get('PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE');
$fields['VERSION']=56;
$fields['PROFILESTARTDATE']='2015-10-20T00:00:00Z';
$fields['DESC']="xxx";
$fields['BILLINGPERIOD']='Month';
$fields['BILLINGFREQUENCY']=1;
$fields['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES']=12;
$fields['AMT']=5;
$fields['TRIALBILLINGPERIOD']='Month';
$fields['TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY']=1;
$fields['TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']=1;
$fields['TRIALAMT']=1;
$fields['CURRENCYCODE']='USD';
$fields['COUNTRYCODE']='US';
```

i have specified the total billing cycle as 12 for one year. can i use total billing cycle as 60 for five years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set parameter $fields['INITAMT'] = $1; and other parameters for recurring payment to $5 for month:

```
$hosteddata['INITAMT']  = 1;
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = 5;
$hosteddata['AMT'] = 5;
```

In this case you will charge 1$ immediately and after that each month will charge $5 for recurring payment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use total billing cycle as 60 for five years, there is no problem.
You can have a try.